# Java save image pixels into an array & draw image

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a game where you only download the jar, and when you download the jar, the game will download the new cache.

Meanwhile I want to show a nice background, without loading it off a link, I've thought of this idea, I am not sure if it is possible though.

Every image is loaded and is being drawn pixel by pixel, is it possible to get ALL pixels colors of an image, width, height and then print the values & then put them in an array eg:

```
public int[] imagePixels = new int[]{PUT PIXELS HERE...};
```

And then simply use a method to draw that background? Is that possible to do?

Are there any better solutions for this like packing the image into the jar or something?

Explanation:

You have an image, I want to load that image and load every single pixel, we start from row 0, by width & height.

I want to collect every single pixel and save it into an image, so then I can load the image without using any file, and just draw the pixels off the array.

Comment: please whats the question, for better help sooner post an SSCCE or MCVE or MCTaRE

Comment: added tiny explanation.

Comment: Yes it possible, but you'd have to load the image to start with and access the raster data, this will also give you the width and height.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can I then print() all of them, and then copy/paste it into an array so when I execute the app again I can simply load these ints as the pixels?

Comment: In theory, yes, but I think you'll find that's an incredibly large amount of data

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well there is no other way to do what I am trying to do? like packing the image into a jar or something?

Comment: About this point, I'm wondering why bother. Why not just load the image at runtime and extract the pixels?

Comment: @MadProgrammer because it's a play.jar file, there is no images downloaded yet, he must download the game files first. And I want the background to show while the files are downloading.

Comment: If  the image data is in the Jar, this would be impossible, as the data is contained in a single compressed file, you'd need the entire file before you could uncompressed it. You could compress a file of pixel data, but you'd have the same problem. You could use an uncompressed file, but this will only increase the amount of data that you need to read across the network

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes put my idea was store the data into the text file, formated like this -26, 55, 34, 44 etc and then copy paste it into the brackets of the array (new byte[]{-26, 55, 34, 44} but rest of the data, But i understand its a lot of data, the array length is 1,8million

Comment: You "could" take something like 100 or so pixel elements (as packed int's), formatted as comma separated String, compress the String and store the result as a Base64 String with in a text file. This way, each line in the file would represent 100 pixels or so which you could read, decode, uncompressed and render. The first line of the file should present the width/height of the image...as an idea...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47054/discussion-between-user3123545-and-madprogrammer)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the basic problems you will face.  Most image formats employee some kind of compression on the image data, they may also append important data about the image to the end of the file, such as the color model information, which makes rendering them as they are read some what difficult.

What you need is some way to write "chunks" of the image to a file that can be easily read back but does not dramatically increase the file size.

My test image started at 301.68 kb and my "chunk" file format end up as 1.42 mb, which I wasn't particularly happy with until I tested a uncompressed file which ended up at 5.63 mb...think I can live for the momement.

The example uses the inbuilt `GZip` compression, you can get better compression by using something like [Apache-Commons-Compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/)

On paper, what this basically does...

- Reads a chunk of the pixel data, writing this to a comma-separated `String`, where it each value is a given pixel value from the image.  The example reads 10% of the file per chunk.
- Each chunk is then compressed using a `GZip` compression
- The resulting compressed bytes are then encoded using a `Base64` encoding.  Personally I'd prefer to use [`Apache-Commons-Encode`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) as it places less relience on an internal/private class.
- The resulting encoded `String` is then written to a `File` and a new line is placed at the end of the line.

The image is loaded in reverse...

- A line is read from the file (Base64 encoded `String`)
- The `String` is decoded (to a compressed `byte` array)
- The `byte` array is then decompressed into a comma separated `String`
- The comma separated `String` is then `split` and the resulting pixel data is drawn to a backing buffer
- The resulting backing buffer is updated to the screen...

The theory is all good, the implementation is...a little messy, sorry, could be a little tidier, but you get the idea.

The intention with this idea would be to not read the entire `Image.dat` file at once, but instead, leaving it where it is and read a line at a time...this allows for latency.

Now, in this example, I've used a `javax.swing.Timer` to inject a little pause, to be honest, it would be better to use a `SwingWorker`...but I'm sure you get the idea...

[image: SlowLoad]

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ConvertImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            exportImage(new File("/path/to/your/image.jpg"), new File("Image.dat"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        new ConvertImage();
    }

    public ConvertImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int imgWidth = 0;
        private int imgHeight = 0;

        private BufferedReader br = null;
        private BufferedImage imgBuffer;
        private int offset;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Image.dat")));
                String header = br.readLine();
                String[] parts = header.split("x");
                imgWidth = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                imgHeight = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

                imgBuffer = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Graphics2D g2d = null;
                        try {
                            String text = br.readLine();
                            if (text != null) {
                                // Decode the String back to a compressed byte array
                                byte[] decode = Base64.decode(text);
                                GZIPInputStream zis = null;
                                try {
                                    // Decompress the byte array
                                    zis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decode));
                                    // Build the text representation of the pixels
                                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                    int bytesRead = -1;
                                    while ((bytesRead = zis.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                                        sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8"));
                                    }
                                    // Split the pixels into individual packed ints
                                    String[] elements = sb.toString().split(",");
                                    g2d = imgBuffer.createGraphics();
                                    for (String element : elements) {
                                        Point p = getPointAt(offset, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                        g2d.setColor(new Color(Integer.parseInt(element), true));
                                        g2d.drawLine(p.x, p.y, p.x, p.y);
                                        offset++;
                                    }
                                    g2d.dispose();
                                    repaint();
                                } catch (Exception exp) {
                                    exp.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                try {
                                    br.close();
                                } catch (Exception exp) {
                                }
                                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            try {
                                br.close();
                            } catch (Exception exp) {
                            }
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                g2d.dispose();
                            } catch (Exception exp) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = (getWidth() - imgBuffer.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - imgBuffer.getHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawImage(imgBuffer, x, y, this);
        }

    }

    protected static void exportImage(File in, File out) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();

        // Calculate the total "length" of the image
        int imageLength = width * height;
        // Calculate the length of each line we will produce
        // This is the number of pixels per chunk
        int runLength = Math.round((width * height) * 0.1f);

        // The place to write the output
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out));
            bw.write(width + "x" + height);
            bw.newLine();

            // Start converting the pixels...
            int offset = 0;
            while (offset < imageLength) {

                // Calculate the size of the next buffer run, we don't want to 
                // over run the end of the image
                int bufferSize = runLength;
                if (offset + bufferSize > imageLength) {
                    bufferSize = imageLength - offset;
                }

                // Create a buffer to store the pixel results in...
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize * 2);
                for (int index = 0; index < bufferSize; index++) {
                    Point p = getPointAt(offset + index, width, height);
                    if (sb.length() > 0) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                    // Store the pixel
                    sb.append(img.getRGB(p.x, p.y));
                }
                // Write the contents to a compressed stream...
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                GZIPOutputStream zos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
                zos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                zos.flush();
                zos.close();
                // Encode the compressed results to Base64
                String encoded = Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
                // Write the content...
                bw.write(encoded);
                bw.newLine();

                // Jump to the next "chunk"
                offset += bufferSize;
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static Point getPointAt(int index, int width, int height) {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.y = index / width;
        p.x = index % width;
        return p;
    }

}
```