# Java BufferedImage write / read (different rgb values)

Tags: java, image, rgb, bufferedimage

I wrote an image with this code:

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

        int r = ciphered[index++];
        int g = ciphered[index++];
        int b = ciphered[index++];

        Color newColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        newImage.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
    }
}
File ouptut = new File("/Users/newbie/Desktop/encrypted.jpg");
ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", ouptut);
```

When I try to read the image ("encrypted.jpg") I get different RGB values. I read the image with the following code:

```
File input = new File("/Users/newbie/Desktop/encrypted.jpg");

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
image = ImageIO.read(input);
int[] t = new int[width * height * 3];

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

        Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));

        int r = c.getRed();
        int g = c.getGreen();
        int b = c.getBlue();

        t[index++] = r;
        t[index++] = g;
        t[index++] = b;
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I just get different rgb values from the ones I've inserted.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy compression, this means that the pixel data may be modified to allow for a better compression

Comment: Thank you. I get it, so is there any way I could save the picture in raw? I need the rgb values to be the ones I want.

Comment: Sure, I've saved the pixel data (ints) to a text field and used the inbuilt zip support to compress it, it's nothing like png or jpg, but it can work

Comment: [This is a slightly sideways example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636477/java-save-image-pixels-into-an-array-draw-image/21640161#21640161), I'd personally write the byte information directly out through a `ZipOutputStream` to a file, but you get the basic idea.  You should also try using `png` of `jpg`, as it uses a lossless compression and would safe you a considerable amount of time and effort